# How to get name of my manifest resource?

Tags: c#, xml, reflection, manifest

So I'm trying to use the [`Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream Method (String)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc4235zt(v=vs.110).aspx)

I have my xsd file in one folder nested within some other folder inside my Project.

What exactly is this manifest name and how is it inferred? Is it constructed from the relative path or what?

Comment: The name is: default namespace of your assembly (look at Project > Properties > Default namespace).Folder.Subfolder.File

Comment: So after assembly name it's just folder stucture?

Comment: Not assembly name but _default namespace_ (which can be the same but can be different). After that yes - folder structure separated by dots.

Comment: Ok but I'm like, really confident that I endered the whole string correctly and it just returns null. What I'd actually prefer is if it threw one of the exceptions they mention on the docs. If the path is incorrect it should be throwing FileLoadException right? Is there some other reason for this function to just return null?

Comment: Well maybe you not marked target file as resource (build action > embedded resource). Anyhow the best way to diagnose the problem is to run `Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames()` and check if your resource is there. If not - it's not a resource (see above). If yes - you will see it's correct name.

Comment: You are my saviour! I forgot about this completely